# ImageButton is not filing out is Linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

In below code there are some of the `ImageButton` having `ImageButton` out of which hotel_english and weather images are not proper in linearlayout. Here I am applying scaletype fillXY so please help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">     
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="3">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/hotelslayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >
                        <ImageView
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:id="@+id/hotelsbtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/hotels_english"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/weatherlayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="2">
                        <Button
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:id="@+id/weatherbtn"
                            android:layout_below= "@+id/hotelsbtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/weather_english"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/trackerlayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".29">
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/tackerbtn"
                            android:layout_below= "@+id/trackerbtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/tracker_english"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Linear Layout` to have definite positioning, you should always include `android:orientation = "<value>"` in it.